# ASP.NET Core Logging With ActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, action-filter

I am trying to add a logging function to save to my SQL server database. I tried to create ActionFilter  class and apply on one of my controller but not working.
i want to capture userid, IP address, controller and action visit and timestamp. What am i missing?

```
AuditAttribute Action Filter class

public class AuditAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    //Inject ApplicationDBContext
    public AuditAttribute(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

         //Stores the Request in an Accessible object
         var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        //Generate an audit
        Portal_Logger audit = new Portal_Logger()
        {
            teacherNRIC = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name,
            IPAddress = Convert.ToString(ipHostInfo.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(address => address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)),
            ControllerAccess = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"],
            Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
        };

         public DbSet<Portal_Logger> Portal_LoggerDBSet { get; set; }
        //Store objects to database
        _db.Portal_LoggerDBSet.Add(audit);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

}
}     


Home controller class
[AuditAttribute]
public class HomeController : Controller
{ ..content of controller
}


Portal_logger model class
public class Portal_Logger
{
    [Key]
    public int LoggerId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string userid{ get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ControllerAccess { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }

}
```

Please see the error message as attached image
[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iETGt.png)

I tried and have a new issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94XCV.png)

I tried this method also not working.
    [AuditActionFilter] -> Error message (AuditActionFilter is not an attribute class)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

---

I tried this method but not working still.

```
[AuditActionFilter] - error message -> "AuditActionFilter" is not an 
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

I have added services.AddMVC to startup.cs
`services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(typeof(AuditActionFilter)));`

This is the AuditActionFilter.cs

```
public class AuditActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public AuditActionFilter(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        Portal_Logger audit = new Portal_Logger()
        {
            teacherNRIC = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name,
            IPAddress = Convert.ToString(ipHostInfo.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(address => address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)),
            ControllerAccess = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"],
            Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
        };

        //Store objects to database
        _db.Portal_LoggerDBSet.Add(audit);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // do something after the action executes or leave it empty
    }

}
```

Comment: What's not working? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using `AuditAttribute` on the specific method or controller, you could try `ServiceFilterAttribute` or `TypeFilterAttribute`.

Here are the available two options:

**Option1**

Use `TypeFilterAttribute`.

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(AuditAttribute))]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

**Option2**

Use `ServiceFilterAttribute`

1. Register `AuditAttribute` in `Startup.cs`

   ```
    services.AddScoped<AuditAttribute>();
   ```
2. Use `AuditAttribute`

   ```
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(AuditAttribute))]
    public class HomeController : Controller
   ```

Comment: Can I have more details for Option 1 and 2 ?

Comment: @xingtan check this document [Dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#dependency-injection)

Comment: Tks Tao Zhou. Will check that out.

Comment: Any idea how to set properties of the action filter attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because you have a parameter of "DbContext" on your attribute, but you are not supplying it when applying it to the controller?

```
public AuditAttribute(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    _db = db;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to use DI in Action filters is described here:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/custom-filter-in-mvc-or-logging-using-mvc-filter

The article in short:

**Enable for all controllers:**

starup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>  
{  
   options.Filters.Add(typeof(AuditAttribute));  
});
```

**Enable for only one controller:**

starup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<AuditAttribute>();
```

Next you place on the controller or action method:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(AuditAttribute))]
```